# "package does not exist" in multimodule build with maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, build, multi-module

I have a Spring Boot Project called "Organizer" with 5 Modules:

- application
- backend
- client-api
- core
- discord-bot

Core is a dependency in all other modules.
And all modules are dependencies in the "application" module

Whenever I want to run `mvn clean install` on organizer ir builds everything until it reaches the "discord-bot" module, there it fails saying `package net.dragoncoding.organizer.core does not exist` meanwhile the IDE shows no errors at all.
[image: The error message]
[image: Build Progress]

When I manually use `mvn clean install` on all the modules I can build them all and also build the project.

Is there something I am missing here?

IntelliJ Version:
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-231.9161.38, built on June 20, 2023

**EDIT:**
Here's the Project pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.dragoncoding</groupId>
    <artifactId>Organizer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Organizer</name>
    <description>Organizer</description>

    <modules>
        <module>application</module>
        <module>client-api</module>
        <module>backend</module>
        <module>discord-bot</module>
        <module>core</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.42.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>net.dragoncoding.organizer.app.Application</mainClass>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here the pom.xml for the core module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>net.dragoncoding</groupId>
        <artifactId>Organizer</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>core</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

And here the pom.ml for the `discord-bot` module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>net.dragoncoding</groupId>
        <artifactId>Organizer</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>discord-bot</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dragoncoding</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dragoncoding</groupId>
            <artifactId>client-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-beta.11</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>club.minnced</groupId>
                    <artifactId>opus-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you share your `pom.xml` file/files?

Comment: @chameerar I added the relevant pom.xml

Comment: You may need to just reorder modules in the parent pom.xml file, the `core` should be higher than `discord-bot` in your case, it should solve the issue

Comment: See official Maven docs around that: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

Comment: Sadly it still fails, It already builds it in the right order too (see screenshot). But it fails as soon as it reaches the ```discord-bot``` module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the whole `<build>` node from the root `Organizer` module's POM file to the `application` sub-module's POM file.

What is happening is by defining spring-boot-maven-plugin:repackage in the root POM, every sub-module inherits it. So the `core` sub-module dutifully executes this repackage goal, and re-arranges the classes in the JAR to something to be started from the command line. This is why the compiler cannot find anything in `net.dragoncoding.organizer.core`. What you really want is only the `application` sub-module to be re-packaged so it is runnable from the command line.

Examine the contents of the `core` jar file before and after this change by doing a `jar tf ~/.m2/repository/net/dragoncoding/core/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Notice how the `org/dragoncoding` classes are now at the root instead of under `BOOT-INF/classes`.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've done an `mvn clean install` manually, right-click on the root project in IntelliJ IDEA, and select Maven => Reload project. Then try again.

Sometimes IntelliJ just needs a gentle nudge in these situations.

Comment: It breaks again, no change to before

Comment: Can you share the source code repo?

Comment: Shalme here's the github repo https://github.com/DragonCoding-Reiko/Organizer